# RTMP stream on IE dies after ~1 second

Tags: video, video-streaming, jwplayer, rtmp, jwplayer6

Follow-up from: [RTMP stream plays sound for 1 second, then stops - no video at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23543517/rtmp-stream-plays-sound-for-1-second-then-stops-no-video-at-all)

The behavior here is really strange.

My config:

```
jwplayer('canvas').setup({
    file : "stream.smil",
    width : 1024,
    height : 768,
    stagevideo : false,
    autostart : true
});
```

`stream.smil`:

```
<smil>
  <head>
    <meta base="rtmp://192.168.1.160:1340/live/" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <switch>
      <video src="large" width="1024" height="768" system-bitrate="2000000" />
      <video src="small" width="640" height="480" system-bitrate="800000" />
    </switch>
  </body>
</smil>
```

So, okay, turning off `stagevideo` (GPU rendering) helped with the white video, but the audio problem remains, though, I have some new information.

My RTMP server is [nginx with rtmp module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module), listening on `1340` (as smil suggests).
I have a Mobotix IP Camera which output I use as an input for my ffmpeg, that then feeds the RTMP server:

```
ffmpeg -f mxg -i "http://admin:meinsm@192.168.1.161:80/control/faststream.jpg?stream=MxPEG&needlength" -f flv -ar 44100 -s 1024x768 "rtmp://localhost:1340/live/large"
```

Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari works as expected, IE though, that's a totally different miraculous world:

1. Once I open the page, I can almost immediately hear audio, then it takes some time to load video, once it loads, it plays for about 1s, then the audio stops and video freezes.
2. If I switch to a lower quality stream, same happens - I can almost immediately hear audio, takes time to load video, once loads - ~1s and dead.
3. If I restart the ffmpeg feeder without pausing/closing the player/stream itself, then,  after a short amount of time the player starts to play both, the audio and the video with no interruptions. If at some point I change streams again or reload the page - we're back to #1. I can then again restart ffmpeg feeder and the video will continue as if nothing had happened.

I feel that it might be an issue with the MxPEG live stream, because it uses it's own codec and has some differences from default codecs, one of them being <sup>(http://developer.mobotix.com/docs/params.html)</sup>:

> **Instead of I-frames...**
>
> With the current MxPEG implementation, there is no way to tell the codec to include a full JPEG frame, say, every second or every 20 frames. Therefore, there's no I-Frame concept known from other codecs. But the way sketched above, jumping back one second and start decoding, may serve as a practical workaround.

There is extra information about the codec itself available [here](http://developer.mobotix.com/docs/how.html).

Though, even if there is such a difference, that doesn't explain why it's only IE that doesn't work (though, it has no problems if I restart the feed while the player is reading from RTMP).

I'm out of clues here, I have tried changing FLV codec to x264 with AAC - Chrome, Opera, Firefox, Safari works, IE doesn't (different problem though).

I also tried feeding ffmpeg a static video file as input (Blenders' Sintel video, mp4) using the same options for RTMP output - there I had consistent problems, the video stuttered on all browsers, but it did play.

But yes, somebody maybe have got a clue what is wrong here?

Comment: Is the stream up right now? I am trying to watch the stream right now but it just buffers, not only in IE, but every browser at the moment.

Comment: Damn, it really appears to be dead - out of office, cannot restart it. Will see why and get it up tomorrow.

Comment: Ok, thank you, please keep be posted.

Comment: The feeder had died, I set it up again and set it to auto-restart if it dies.

Comment: Yeah, it is up now. How can I check when it stops though since the screen is static? Is seems to be working fine.

Comment: Clock at the top right corner and sound.

Comment: What version of IE has the issue for you?

Comment: IE11 (W7). And in compatibility mode others too.

Comment: I started the stream in IE11 and Firefox on my machine at the same time at 5:04 PM EST. It is currently 5:07 PM EST and both browsers are still streaming and the clocks are counting up in both of them.

Comment: Woah, that's weird. Are there any debugging options for JW? Stream status checking? Like data that has been read (bytes) and such per sec.?

Comment: A colleague of mine has reported that it doesn't work for him with the same bug on native IE10 (W7).

Comment: You could use the Flash debug player. I am using Win7, IE11, Flash 13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what's the problem: https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/issues/340

Actually, documentation even says that it should be enabled by default: https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Directives#wait_video

Yes, apparently, if you're running nginx rtmp module for RTMP hosting, you need to set:

```
wait_video on;
```

In your RTMP applications' configuration block.